# Multiple Data Binding Objects in Eclipse Jface MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jface

I'm facing some problems regarding a jFace TableViewer and its bindings. I'm using the following example code for the TableViewer:

```
public class AppPersonViewer extends TableViewer
{
    public Table table;
    
    public AppPersonViewer(Composite parent, int style) 
    {
        super(parent, style);
        table = getTable();
        GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        table.setLayoutData(gridData);
        createColumns();
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        setContentProvider(new AppContentProvider());
    }

    private void createColumns()
    {
        String[] titles = { "First Name", "Second Name", "Age", "Country", "Likes SO" };
        int[] bounds = { 150, 150, 100, 150, 100 };

        TableViewerColumn column = createTableViewerColumn(titles[0], bounds[0], 0);
        column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
            public String getText(Object element) {
                if(element instanceof Person)
                    return ((Person)element).getFirst();
                return super.getText(element);
            }
        });

        column = createTableViewerColumn(titles[1], bounds[1], 1);
        column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
            public String getText(Object element) {
                if(element instanceof Person)
                    return ((Person)element).getSecond();
                return super.getText(element);
            }
        });

        column = createTableViewerColumn(titles[2], bounds[2], 2);
        column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
            public String getText(Object element) {
                if(element instanceof Person)
                    return ""+((Person)element).getAge();
                return super.getText(element);
            }
        });

        column = createTableViewerColumn(titles[3], bounds[3], 3);
        column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
            public String getText(Object element) {
                if(element instanceof Person)
                    return ((Person)element).getCountry();
                return super.getText(element);
            }
        });
  
        column = createTableViewerColumn(titles[4], bounds[4], 4);
        column.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
            public Image getImage(Object element) {
                    return ((Person)element).getImage();
            }
            
            public String getText(Object element) {
                  return null;  // no string representation, we only want to display the image
                }
            
        });
        
        
    }

    private TableViewerColumn createTableViewerColumn(String header, int width, int idx) 
    {
        TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(this, SWT.LEFT, idx);
        column.getColumn().setText(header);
        column.getColumn().setWidth(width);
        column.getColumn().setResizable(true);
        column.getColumn().setMoveable(true);

        return column;
    }
}
```

The Person object is used here for the data binding:

```
import java.util.Random;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;

public class Person 
{
    private static final String[]   FIRST = {"Favonius", "Tim", "Brad", "Scott", "Linda"};
    private static final String[]   SECOND = {"Cruise", "Temp", "Abbey", "Adam", "Albert", "Thomas"};
    private static final String[]   COUNTRY = {"India", "USA", "Russia", "UK", "France", "Germany"};
    private static final int[]      AGE = {22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30};

    private static Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    private String first;
    private String second;
    private String country;
    private String likes;

    private int age;

    public Person(String first, String second, String country, String likes, int age) 
    {
        super();
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.country = country;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }
    public String getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public String getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setLikes(String likes) {
        this.likes = likes;
    }
    
    public Image getImage(){
        return Display.getDefault().getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_ERROR);
    }
    
    public static Person createRandomPerson(){
        return new  Person(FIRST[random.nextInt(FIRST.length)], 
                SECOND[random.nextInt(SECOND.length)], COUNTRY[random.nextInt(COUNTRY.length)], 
                "Y", AGE[random.nextInt(AGE.length)]);
    }
}
```

This example binds only one object to the TableViewer. But I want to bind multiple objects to the TableViewer. For example column 1 of the TableViewer should hold the attribute test of object A, and Column 2 of the TableViewer should hold the attribute newTest of object B.

Is this possible? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row in a table uses a single object provided by your content provider.

So if you need values from different objects you will need return a composite class containing those objects from the content provider.